# Getting a Error on Case Id : Cannot specify id in an insert call

Tags: apex, dml

I am Getting an error on case id: cannot specify an id in an insert call, in Production but In the sandbox, it's work fine. could you, please help me.

```
public with sharing class SSRACExtensions {    

    public String oppId {get;set;}
    public List<Opportunity> opp {get;set;}    
    public SSR__c ssr {get;set;}
    public Case cse {get;set;}



    public SSRACExtensions(ApexPages.StandardController controller) {        
        oppId = ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('oppid');                               
        initalization();
    }

    public void initalization(){    
        ssr = new SSR__c();           
        cse = new Case();
        if(oppId!=null){
            opp = [SELECT id,AccountId,Account.Name,Name,OwnerId,Owner.Name FROM Opportunity where id=:oppId limit 1];      
            if(opp.size()>0){

                ssr.Opportunity_Name__c  = opp[0].id;                
                ssr.Account_Name__c = opp[0].AccountId;
                ssr.Sales_Rep__c = opp[0].Owner.Name;

                //------case initalization-----------
                cse.Opportunity_Owner__c= opp[0].Owner.Name ;
                cse.AccountId = opp[0].AccountId;                             
                cse.Case_Type__c= 'Sales Support';
                cse.Status = 'New';
                cse.Intaited_by__c = 'Internal';
                cse.Priority = 'High';        
                cse.Department__c = 'Sales';                
                cse.Origin = 'test';
            }
        }        
    }

    public PageReference saveSSR(){
        if(oppId!=null){
            try{                
                cse.Subject = ssr.Subject__c;       
                cse.Description = ssr.Note__c;                    
                Database.DMLOptions dmlOpts = new Database.DMLOptions();
                dmlOpts.assignmentRuleHeader.useDefaultRule = true;
                cse.setOptions(dmlOpts);                
                insert cse;

                ssr.Case__c = cse.Id;
                insert ssr;  

                PageReference pg = new PageReference('/'+oppId);
                return pg;                                                  
            }catch(System.DMLException e){
                ApexPages.Message msg = new ApexPages.Message(ApexPages.Severity.ERROR, 'Due to miscellaneous reasons the Save operation failed.');
                ApexPages.addMessage(msg); 
                return null;
            }
        }else{
            try{
                String opId = ssr.Opportunity_Name__c;
                opp = [SELECT id,AccountId,Account.Name,Name,OwnerId,Owner.Name FROM Opportunity where id=:opId limit 1];
                //------case initalization-----------
                cse.Opportunity_Owner__c= opp[0].Owner.Name ;
                cse.AccountId = opp[0].AccountId;                             
                cse.Case_Type__c= 'Sales Support';
                cse.Status = 'New';
                cse.Intaited_by__c = 'Internal';
                cse.Priority = 'High';        
                cse.Department__c = 'Sales';                
                cse.Origin = 'Demo';
                cse.Subject = ssr.Subject__c;       
                cse.Description = ssr.Note__c;    

                Database.DMLOptions dmlOpts = new Database.DMLOptions();
                dmlOpts.assignmentRuleHeader.useDefaultRule = true;
                cse.setOptions(dmlOpts);                
                insert cse;

                ssr.Case__c = cse.Id;
                insert ssr;                        

            }catch(System.DMLException e){
                ApexPages.Message msg = new ApexPages.Message(ApexPages.Severity.ERROR, 'Due to miscellaneous reasons the Save operation failed.');
                ApexPages.addMessage(msg); 
                return null;
            }
            PageReference pg = new PageReference('/'+ssr.id);
            return pg;

        }
    }
    public pageReference cancelMethod(){
        if(oppId!=null){
            PageReference pg = new PageReference('/'+oppId);
            return pg;
        }else{
            PageReference pg = new PageReference(ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('retURL'));
            return pg;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are trying to insert a record with ID field. This will cause error because record is already created. You could probably need to do an `Update`.

In case you are not sure about record exists or not, use **UPSERT**. It performs like Insert or Update. If there is an id field it will update the record else it insert a new record. Replace `insert` with `upsert`.

Comment: @GmDeepakChounan21 did this resolved your issue?

Answer (score 0):

When you handle a `DMLException` in a controller, it is possible to end up with an SObject that has the Id value assigned that would have been used if the insert had succeeded. But this is not an Id value that can be updated or upserted.

I suggest that when the `DMLException` is handled, you re-build the objects (e.g. call `initalization()`) to ensure the Id value is cleared out.

You can confirm that this is the cause by finding examples in your sandbox where no `DMLException` occurs (where the save should work) and where a `DMLException` does happen (where the save should fail).